# Create sobject record type in unit test

Tags: apex, unit-test, record-type

We have a logic that does changes depends on empty/master record type or a custom one. Is it possible to create a test record type and assign it to the record? We wanted to add unit test coverage for each case.

Source: 2ng generation managed package

Comment: Is there a reason you need to create a new one and can't use an existing record type?

Comment: No, you can't create a Record Type in a unit test. You must use an existing record type. Without more context, however, we won't be able to help you. Is this for a 2GP? Unlocked Package? Etc? Please [edit] your question to give us some background. Also, read about the [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) for more information.

Comment: @sfdcfox updated the original post with more details